# How to deal with error:SQL Error [58P01]?

Tags: postgresql

I'm learning PostgreSQL, and i run into problem:
I have created table and trying to export it, but I have all the time same error

```
SQL Error [58P01]: ERROR: could not open file "D:\Janis\Mācības\SQL\Test\typestest.txt" for writing: No such file or directory
Hint: COPY TO instructs the PostgreSQL server process to write a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.
```

Script that I'm running:

```
CREATE TABLE char_data_types (
    varchar_column varchar(10),
    char_column char(10),
    text_column text
);

INSERT INTO char_data_types
VALUES
    ('abc', 'abc', 'abc'),
    ('defghi', 'defghi', 'defghi');

COPY char_data_types TO 'D:\Janis\Mācības\SQL\Test\typestest.txt'
WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER, DELIMITER '|');
```

I have taken off all possible security restriction from file typestest.txt

Comment: Documentation says: "Windows users might need to use an E'' string and double any backslashes used in the path name."

Comment: Tried that, didn't work

Comment: The path name of the input or output file. An input file name can be an absolute or relative path, but an output file name must be an absolute path. Windows users might need to use an E'' string and double any backslashes used in the path name.

Comment: Is `D:` a local directory or a mapped network drive? What are the folder permissions? It also won't hurt to test with a path that only contains plain English characters, just in case.

Comment: To your question add: 1) Where are you running this script? 2) Have you changed the permission on the directories above the file? 3)  Use `/` slash instead of  `\\``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no directory `D:\Janis\Mācības\SQL\Test` on the PostgreSQL **server**. Note that `COPY` writes to the database server, no the client (the statement runs on the server, and the server cannot access the client machine).

To export the data to the client machine, you have to use `psql` so that you can use `\copy`:

```
\copy char_data_types TO 'D:\Janis\Mācības\SQL\Test\typestest.txt' WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER, DELIMITER '|')
```

The command has to be in a single line.

Comment: I am not following, if the Postgres server is running on Windows there could very well be a directory `D:\Janis\Mācības\SQL\Test`. It also highly probable that the server does not have permissions on that directory, in which case from it's view point it is unreachable.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I don't have high confidence in the accuracy of Windows error messages, but wouldn't you assume that "No such file or directory" indicates a missing directory? If it were a permission problem, I'd expect something like "permission denied".

Comment: Alright, faulty memory on  my part. I just cranked up a Windows machine and I got a 'Permission denied' error when trying a `COPY ... TO ` statement where `TO` pointed at an existing directory.